# Java - Multi-threaded crawler with ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I'm working to make a crawler in Java. I made a single-threaded crawler to visit a single page and fetch all links on that page. Now I want to make it multi-threaded but facing difficulties. In the very beginning I start with single link of the page and crawl through all the links in it and Now I want to run an *ExecutorService* in which the thread starts with fetching a single url from *unvisitedLinks* and start working on it just like it did with a single-threaded crawler and same for a few more threads doing the same thing. Here is the crawler class I made which implements *Runnable* to make it a thread:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class MyCrawler implements Runnable {
    volatile static int counter =0;
    String originaUrl, currentUrl;
    List<String> unvisitedLinks = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> visitedLinks = new HashSet<>();
    URI uri;
    ExecutorService executor = null;
    int pagesVisited = 0;


    public MyCrawler(String url) {
        this.originaUrl = url;
        unvisitedLinks.add(url);
         this.uri = URI.create(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        do{
            try{
                executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
                String url; 
                synchronized (this) {
                    url = unvisitedLinks.get(0);
                    while (unvisitedLinks.contains(url)) {
                        unvisitedLinks.remove(url);
                    }
                }
                //Visit this page and fetch all the links;
                VisitPage(url);

                visitedLinks.add(url);

                for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
                    synchronized (this) {
                        url = unvisitedLinks.get(i);
                        while (unvisitedLinks.contains(url)) {
                            unvisitedLinks.remove(url);
                        }
                    }
                    Runnable worker = new MyCrawler(url);
                    executor.execute(worker);
                }

                executor.shutdown();
                while(!executor.isTerminated()){ //WAIT FOR EXECUTOR TO FINISH

                }
                executor = null;
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }while(unvisitedLinks.size() != 0);
        System.out.println("total pages visited: " + counter);
        System.out.println("TOTAL LINKS FOUND " + visitedLinks.size());

        for(String s: visitedLinks){
            System.out.println(s + "\n");
        }
    }

    private void VisitPage(String url){

        List<String> linksOnthisPage = new ArrayList<>();

        if(!visitedLinks.contains(url)){
            if(!url.contains("javascript") && !url.contains("#")){

                try{
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();
                    Elements linkTags = doc.select("a[href]");

                    for(Element e : linkTags){
                        String link = e.attr("href");
                        if(!visitedLinks.contains(link) && !link.contains("#") && !link.contains("javascript") && !link.equals(url)){
                            if(link.startsWith("http") || link.startsWith("www")){
                                if(link.contains(uri.getHost())){
                                    linksOnthisPage.add(link);
                                }else{
                                    System.out.println("SOME OTHER WEBSITE -- " + link);
                                }

                            }else if(link.startsWith("/")){
                                link = url + link.substring(1, link.length());
                                linksOnthisPage.add(link);
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("LINK IGNORED DUE TO  -- " + url);
                            }
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("LINK IGNORED -- " + url);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n\nLinks found in \"" + url+ "\" : " + linksOnthisPage.size());
                    unvisitedLinks.addAll(linksOnthisPage);
                    System.out.println("UNVISITED LINKS NOW: " + unvisitedLinks.size());
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("EXCEPTION -- " + url);
                    return;
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("UNWANTED URL -- " + url);
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("LINK VISITED -- " + url);
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the main method where I'm submitting the link to start with.

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            Thread t = new Thread(new MyCrawler("http://www.example.com/"));

            t.start();
            t.join();
            System.out.println("\nFinished all threads\n---------------------------------");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("DONE!");


    }

}
```

P.S There may be a lot of blunders you will go through in this code. Please correct me in every way you can.

Comment: You should separate the job(Runnable) class from the Executor class. In your solution you will instantiate the thread pool on each time you call execute on Runnable.

Comment: But, what is the question/problem ?

Comment: So... what is your question? Edit: beaten :-)

Comment: My question here is this code isn't working as expected. May be there is some Thread interference in my code.

Comment: _...this code isn't working as expected..._   You're more likely to get help if you tell people what you expect the code to do instead of asking them to read 140 lines of code that _doesn't_ do what you expected and then try to guess what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you need to do is to handle in the Runnables the url visiting part only, which means that the Runnable class will be kind of this :

```
public class MyCrawler implements Runnable {

    URI uri;



    public MyCrawler(String url) {
         this.uri = URI.create(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{
            VisitPage(url);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private void VisitPage(String url){

        List<String> linksOnthisPage = new ArrayList<>();

        if(!url.contains("javascript") && !url.contains("#")){

            try{
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();
                Elements linkTags = doc.select("a[href]");

                for(Element e : linkTags){
                    String link = e.attr("href");
                    if(!link.contains("#") && !link.contains("javascript") && !link.equals(url)){
                        if(link.startsWith("http") || link.startsWith("www")){
                            if(link.contains(uri.getHost())){
                                linksOnthisPage.add(link);
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("SOME OTHER WEBSITE -- " + link);
                            }

                        }else if(link.startsWith("/")){
                            link = url + link.substring(1, link.length());
                            linksOnthisPage.add(link);
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("LINK IGNORED DUE TO  -- " + url);
                        }
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("LINK IGNORED -- " + url);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("\n\nLinks found in \"" + url+ "\" : " + linksOnthisPage.size());

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("EXCEPTION -- " + url);
                return;
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("UNWANTED URL -- " + url);
        }
    }

}
```

Next loop over the links and add a job to the executor for each url,( you can do this in your main method or do it in a new class), the code snippet will look like this :

```
for(String url : unvisitedLinks ){
{
    Runnable worker = new MyCrawler(url);
    executor.execute(worker);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to consider several things before starting:

1. How to avoid revisiting the already seen pages?
2. When is the time to terminate the thread pool?
3. How to notify the main thread that all the tasks have already finished, so that the main thread can output the sitemap?

To solve first question, we need to remember if a link has been visited or not by a map.

To solve the second question, we need a counter and increase it by 1 each time a new task is submitted, and decrease by 1 each time a task is finished. When the counter gets to zero, it means we have finished all the tasks.

To solve the the third question, we need some kind of synchronization mechanism between the main thread and the thread pool.

And now we have some solution like this

```
public class Worker {

public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Worker.class);

private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean> visited = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Set<String>> graph = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private final String domain;
private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

public final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
private final CountDownLatch done;

public Worker(String domain, CountDownLatch done) {
    this.domain = domain;
    this.done = done;
}

public void start() {
    executorService.submit(new CrawlTask(domain));
}

public ConcurrentHashMap<String, Set<String>> getGraph() {
    return graph;
}

public class CrawlTask implements Runnable {
    public final String url;

    public CrawlTask(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        logger.info("remaining tasks: {}, visiting {}", counter.get(), url);

        Document doc;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(5000).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warn("URL: {}, {}", url, e.toString());
            return;
        }

        Set<String> links = doc.select("a").stream().map(e -> e.attr("abs:href"))
                .filter(l -> Utils.isInDomain(l, domain))
                .map(Utils::trimURL)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        graph.put(url, links);

        for (String link : links) {
            if (!visited.getOrDefault(link, false)) {
                visited.put(link, true);
                counter.getAndIncrement();
                executorService.submit(new CrawlTask(link));
            }
        }

        int n = counter.getAndDecrement();
        if (n == 0) {
            executorService.shutdown();
            try {
                executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                done.countDown();
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

And the main function

```
public class CounterApp {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
    String domain = "https://example.com";
    Worker worker = new Worker(domain, doneSignal);
    worker.start();
    doneSignal.await();

    Map<String, Set<String>> graph = worker.getGraph();
    graph.forEach((k, v) -> {
        System.out.println(k + ": ");
        v.forEach(l -> System.out.println("   " + l));
    });
}}
```

source code [here](https://gitlab.com/shilongzhao/crawler/-/tree/master)